# Don't know what to do with little-oh!

Tags: asymptotics, analytic-number-theory

Let $f:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{C}$ be a function for which there exists a positive constant $A$ such that
\begin{equation}
\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{1}{x}\sum_{n\leq x} f(n) = A. 
\end{equation}
Prove that
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n\leq x} f(n)\log n = A(1+o(1))x\log x ~~~~ (x\to \infty) 
\end{equation}

What I did so far is:

We are given that
\begin{equation}
 \sum_{n\leq x} f(n) = Ax + o(x)
\end{equation}

Hence by Abel summation, if we put $F(x) = \sum_{n\leq x} f(n),$ we have
\begin{align}
 \sum_{n\leq x}f(n)\log n &= F(x) \log x - \int_{1}^x \frac{F(t)}{t}dt \\
              &= (Ax + o(x))\log x -\int_{1}^x \frac{At+o(t)}{t}dt \\ 
    &=(Ax + o(x))\log x - A(x-1)  -\int_{1}^x \frac{o(t)}{t}dt
\end{align}
I dont know what to do next, Also I dont know if I can write 
\begin{equation}
(Ax + o(x))\log x = A(1+o(1))x\log x 
\end{equation}

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Yes, you can write $o(x)$ as $o(1)x$. For $f(x) \in o(x)$ means precisely $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{x} = 0$, i.e. $\frac{f(x)}{x} \in o(1)$.